# Ipad gives flickering effect when modifying the height of an element

Tags: jquery, css, ipad, ios6

In Ipad(iOS 6) I'm facing the flickering effect when modifying the height of an element, However this flickering effect is not occurring in iOS 7.

I'm just using jQuery's height method to modify the height. animate also not seems to solve the issue.

How to fix this flickering effect?

Tried out below options,

1. Using Hardware accelaration (Added -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0); to body, however it made the page too slow, since our page has lot of animations/slides in the page every action became too slow)
2. Adding below CSS for animating div, its parent and child

   ```
   -webkit-perspective: 1000;
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   ```

Comment: Generally from native side, the flickering occurs if we are trying to update `UIEvents` in a child thread. All `UIEvents` should be updated via the applications `main thread`.

Comment: Is the element position fixed or static? Do you have any fiddle demo to show us?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the Hardware Acceleration trick to the element instead of the body. This would make it it's own `composite layer`.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/layers/